# Retrieving value from json array where attribute equals variable with Ansible

Tags: arrays, ansible, attributes

I'm trying to get the value of an attribute in a json array with Ansible. Example data:

```
"domains.json.data": [
        {
            "axfr_ips": [],
            "description": "",
            "domain": "mydomain.net",
            "expire_sec": 0,
            "group": "",
            "id": 687088,
        },
        {
            "axfr_ips": [],
            "description": "",
            "domain": "myotherdomain.net",
            "expire_sec": 0,
            "group": "",
            "id": 687089,
        }
    ]
}
```

So I tried with json query:

```
"{{ domains.json.data | json_query(\"data[?domain=='{{ server_domain }}'].id\") }}"
```

or with:

```
- set_fact:
    domain_id: "{{ domains | json_query(query) | first }}"
  vars:
    query: "domains.json[?name=='{{ server_domain }}'].id"
```

Also tried with selectattrib:

```
"{{ linode_domains.json.data | selectattr(\"domain\", \"{{ server_domain }}\") | list }}"
```

So what I need is to get the id of the domain I got in {{ server_domain }}.

Comment: What's the data you'd want from this example? `["mydomain.net", "myotherdomain.net"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query can't work because there is no attribute `name` in the dictionary

```yaml
        query: "domains.json[?name=='{{ server_domain }}'].id"
```

Use the attribute `domain`. For example the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ domains.json.data|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        server_domain: 'mydomain.net'
        query: "[?domain=='{{ server_domain }}'].id"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": [
        687088
    ]
```

---

Notes

- *json_query* returns a list.
- use filter *first* to get the first element of a list

```yaml
        msg: "{{ domains.json.data|json_query(query)|first }}"
```

Comment: Added  '| first' so I don't get an array with 1 element (id is unique), tx!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `selectattr` to filter and use `map` to get the id value. Below is the sample you can try.

```
- name: Retrieve value from JSON array
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test.domains | selectattr('domain', 'equalto', server_domain) | map(attribute='id') | join(',') }}"
```

As map returns list, I have used `join` to convert to string.

I have set **server_domain value to myotherdomain.net** for testing.

Below is the output of the command

```
TASK [Retrieve value from JSON array] **************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "687089"
}
```

EDIT:
equalto was introduced in v2.8 of jinja2. If you get TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto',  update the jinja2.

To check version use `pip list | grep Jinja2`. 
To update use following command `pip install --upgrade Jinja2`.

Comment: This still throws me 'TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto'' ... 'Unexpected failure during module execution.'

Comment: @willemdh equalto was introduced in v2.8 of jinja2. So you need to update jinja2. To check version use "pip list | grep Jinja2". Try the following command to update "pip install --upgrade Jinja2". I have updated the answer.