# Ansible Convert JSON to dictionary

Tags: json, ansible

I have an HTTP endpoint that returns a JSON. Format below:

```
[
{
    "abbreviation_id": 1,
    "FullName": "Tiger",
    "abbreviation": "tig",
    "active": true,
    "createdDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32",
    "modifiedDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32"
},
{
    "abbreviation_id": 69,
    "FullName": "Jaguar",
    "abbreviation": "jag",
    "active": true,
    "createdDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32",
    "modifiedDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32"
}

]
```

After retrieving this, I have a var called {{ AnName }} and I would need to find its equivalent abbreviation from the JSON. I've been searching all day on how to do it so I tried to make a query for it with this code:

```
- name: Get abbreviation
  debug:
  var: item
  loop: "{{ animal_lookups | community.general.json_query(abbreviation_query) }}"
  vars: 
  abbreviation_query: "animal_lookups[?FullName == {{ 
  AnName }}].abbreviation"
```

But I realized I haven't installed community.general yet. Which leads me to ask if is this the best way to do it or is there a way for me to convert the JSON into a dictionary so I can do animal_lookups.AnName. Hopefully something like this:

```
animal_lookups:
Tiger: tig
Jaguar: jag
```

Thank you so much!

UPDATE:: Tried Vladimir's solution but it seems like my animal_lookups is recognized as a dictionary, not a JSON.

This code snippet displays the HTTP call that returns a JSON (shown below) and the task should convert is to a dictionary.

```
 - name: Get Abbreviations
  uri:
   url: "https://{{ function_name }}.azurewebsites.net/api/ListAnimals?code={{ function_code }}"
   method: "GET"
   return_content: yes
   timeout: 60
   body_format: json
  register: animal_lookups
  no_log: "{{ secure_logging }}"

- name: Convert JSON to dict
  set_fact:
   animal_dict: "{{ animal_lookups|
                         items2dict(key_name='FullName',
                                    value_name='abbreviation') }}"
```

In the logs it returns the JSON:

```
 "json": [
        {
            "abbreviation": "tig",
            "active": true,
            "cdl_abbreviation_id": 68,
            "createdDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32",
            "digitalSolution": "Tiger",
            "modifiedDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32"
        },
        {
            "abbreviation": "jag",
            "active": true,
            "cdl_abbreviation_id": 69,
            "createdDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32",
            "digitalSolution": "Jaguar",
            "modifiedDate": "2021-01-25T06:17:32"
           }
       ]
```

but returns the error:

```
"msg": "items2dict requires a list, got <class 'dict'> instead."
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can put in order for it to be MVCE. The code snippet shows my HTTP call (that returns the JSON) and the task that supposedly converts the result of the HTTP call (animal_lookups) into a dictionary. However, when I run the pipeline it sees the animal_lookups as a dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

This questions has been partly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58213536/1930817) but since Ansible 2.9 and the rise of collections, I think it would be useful to answer it again here.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the abbreviation of an animal given its `FullName`, taken from a list of Animals.

The best way I can think of doing it is using `json_query` from the `community.general` collection.

To be safe I would suggest testing if the key `FullName` exists on the object before running the test against the variable `AnName`. And also, add the `first` filter to get the first value of the result. By default, `json_query` returns a list.

Here is a sample `playbooks` I made that includes everything I mentioned:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Load JSON file
      set_fact:
        animal_lookups: "{{ lookup('file', 'animal_lookups.json') | from_json }}"
    - debug:
        var: animal_lookups

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ animal_lookups | community.general.json_query(query) | first }}"
      vars:
        animal_name: Tiger
        query: "[?FullName == '{{ animal_name }}'].abbreviation"
```

To simplify the test, I'm loading the Animal collection from a file, and then running the query as shown. If you want to save the result on another variable you could use the `set_fact` module instead of `debug`.