# Ansible Playbook: how to filter list of dicts with information from a second list of dicts

Tags: ansible

I am learning how to use ansible to automate parts of my network deployment process and I stumbled over a problem I cannot figure out.

For my situation:I have a list of dicts that contain multiple dicts that also contain lists. This basically contains a list of network links betwenn nodes that I have gathered from my source of truth. The .yml file looks like this:

```
---
key1:
  key2:
    - value1: somevalue
      nodes: [valueNode1, valueNode2]
      interfaces: [valueInterface1, valueInterface2]
    - value1: othervalue
      nodes: [othervalueNode1, othervalueNode2]
      interfaces: [othervalueInterface1, othervalueInterface2]
```

Each dict under key2 contains one network link. I then have a second file, lets call it ESSENTIAL_LINKS that is structured the same, but contains fewer network links.

The plan is to have the first file be populated from my source of truth that other people also have access to. The second file contains only those network links that are absolutely essential and lies in a secured spot on my ansible control. I have figured out how to combine those two files by myself. However, before combining the files, I would like to filter any occurence of the links from my ESSENTIAL_LINKS file in the first file.
For example let's say I have an ESSENTIAL link defined that looks like this:

```
- value1: ESSENTIAL
  nodes: [ESSENTIAL_NODE, someotherNode]
  interfaces: [ESSENTIAL_interface, someOtherInteface]
```

How can I make sure, that the links I generated from my source of truth do not contain an entry that looks like this:

```
- value1: differentLink
  nodes: [ESSENTIAL_NODE, differentNode]
  interfaces: [ESSENTIAL_inteface, differentNodeInterface]
```

So my quesiton is, is there a good way to implement this filtering in an ansible playbook?

I tried to use the selectattr filter to isolate those links but only managed to hardcode certain value into that approach. I did not manage to actually use the data from ESSENTIAL_LINKS for this.

Comment: I guess this is already anwsered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208915/retrieving-value-from-json-array-where-attribute-equals-variable-with-ansible